# Perform a POST api request using chainlink in a smart contract with body?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, chainlink

I don't have much experience using ChainLink so I cannot provide many details. I want to add a body to my post request the code above is just an example:

```
Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);

// Set the URL to perform the POST request on
request.add("post", "https://rinkeby-light.eth.linkpool.io/");
request.add("body", "{\"id\":0,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"eth_blockNumber\",\"params\":[]}");
```

Any ideas because the code above did not work ?

Comment: kein plan bre...

Comment: What's the question? That looks correct.

Comment: @Patrick seems like this did not work